# Possible to see resource/disk logs from before restart?

Tags: ubuntu, disk, freeze

I have a home server PC running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS which hosts two Minecraft servers. Normally this runs perfectly fine, but earlier today I passed by and noticed the disk usage LED at an almost constant glow. Logging in I found both servers unresponsive and the Ubuntu GUI extremely sluggish. Although I was able to get into the system, before I could get to the terminals and gracefully shutdown the two servers, the GUI hung up completely and the only thing that worked was REISUB.

Question is, is there any way I can see what caused such insane disk usage from logs, or will the reboot have wiped all that info from the past session? No one was logged into either MC server at the time this happened, but if there's a possible bug or resource leak I want to be able to find it so I don't have to hard reboot again later and disk data loss.

Comment: AFAIK, there are no disk usage logs or similar. However, you can check the system, kernel and ssh logs to possibly get an idea of what happened. Ssh/auth logs should be under `/var/log/auth.log`. You should find more under `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show the end of the log of the previous boot

Comment: I don't use ssh, but I can check to see if this gives any info. After more research it seems to be a memory leak in the GPU driver, which had filled up main memory and was causing the servers to use the disk/pagefile.